# Perl <<= and ^= Meaning

Tags: perl

Hello I´m trying to convert a bunch of Perl scripts to C#. 
A have this piece of code and I don´t know what <<=, ^=, &= means. Can someone please tell me the meaning of the part (???) too?. Thanks in advance.

```
$cwl = 6;
$sr = 1;
    for ($i=0; $i<$gf::field; $i++) {
        $gf::log[$sr] = $i;
        $gf::alog[$i] = $sr;
        $sr <<= 1;
        if ($sr & (1<<$cwl)) {$sr ^= $prim} (???)
        $sr &= $gf::field;
    }
```

Comment: https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Bitwise-And

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are:

- `<<=` = Left shift equal operator, shifts the source variable's bits by *n* places to the left and assign back to source variable.
- `^=` = Bitwise `XOR` equal operator. `XOR`s the source variable by the right hand variable, and assigns to the source variable.
- `&=` = Bitwise `AND` equal operator. `AND`s the source variable and the right hand variable, and assigns the result to the source variable.

The C# equivalents from your code above:

**Left Shift**

```
# Perl code
$sr <<= 1;

// C# code
sr = sr << 1;
```

**Bitwise `XOR`**

```
# Perl code
$sr ^= $prim

// C# code
sr = sr ^ prim
```

**Bitwise `AND`**

```
# Perl code
$sr &= $gf::field

// C# code
sr = sr & gf.field // or whatever you've named $gf::field
```

**Edit following OP comment**

OP asked whether:

```
if ($sr & (1<<$cwl))
```

Can be translated to:

```
cwl=1 << cwl;
if (Convert.ToBoolean(sr) & Convert.ToBoolean(cwl))
```

I think you've made an error here.  `cwl` is *not* reassigned in the original `if` statement in Perl.

In fact, the logic of the operation is to say:

- Is `sr` bitwise `AND` 1 left-shifted by `cwl` true?

I'd be tempted to rewrite the Perl code to:

```
if ((sr & (1 << cwl)) != 0)
```

*Why*? The original statement ascertains whether the result of the `if` statement is `true`.  Any non-zero value in Perl is `true`, therefore we need to perform the operation as per the Perl and test for a non-zero value.

Comment: @ssr1012 A good point, I've added some examples to try to help

Comment: @Martin thank you. Can you tell me if if ($sr & (1<<$cwl)) can be replaced by cwl=1 << cwl ; if (Convert.ToBoolean(sr) & Convert.ToBoolean(cwl))  the lack of variable types is driving me crazy! :)

Comment: @HelenaOliveira I have updated my question with my suggestion in this case.  It's not a straight-forward conversion so you can be forgiven for finding it frustrating!

Comment: @Martin It gives me the following error "Operator '&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'bool'". I have declared var sr = 1 in the begining...what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @HelenaOliveira Apologies, my fault.  The line should be `if ((sr & (1 << cwl)) != 0)`.  I missed the extra brackets.  I've updated the answer too